# The existence of a fiber sequence involving $\mathrm{Spin}(9)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

$\newcommand{\SU}{\mathrm{SU}} \newcommand{\Spin}{\mathrm{Spin}}$There is a fiber sequence $G_2\to \Spin(9) \to \Spin(9)/G_2$, and $G_2$ contains $\SU(3)$ as a subgroup. Is there a space (possibly a topological group) $Y$ which sits in a fiber sequence $\SU(2)\to Y\to \Spin(9)/G_2$, such that there is a canonical map $Y\to \Spin(9)$ which fits into a map of fiber sequences
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\SU(2) @>>> Y @>>> \Spin(9)/G_2\\
@VVV @VVV @| \\
G_2 @>>> \Spin(9) @>>> \Spin(9)/G_2?\\
\end{CD}$$
(I would be happy if such a fiber sequence only existed $2$-locally.)
It suffices to show that the classifying map $\Spin(9)/G_2\to BG_2$ lifts through the canonical map $B\SU(2) = \mathbf{H}P^\infty\to BG_2$. The fiber of this map is $G_2/\SU(2)$, but, unfortunately, this isn't a topological group, as far as I can tell. It may be helpful to note that $G_2/\SU(2)$ is the Stiefel manifold $V_2(\mathbf{R}^7)$.

Here is a candidate for $Y$. The space $\Spin(9)/G_2$ is like
$\SU(2;\mathbf{O})$, and sits in a fiber sequence $S^7\to \Spin(9)/G_2\to
S^{15}$. I believe there is a homotopy pullback square

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Spin(9)/G_2 @>>> B\SU(2)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
S^{15} @>>> B\Spin(5),
\end{CD}$$

where the map $S^{15}\to B\Spin(5)$ detects the generator(?) of $\pi_{14}
\Spin(5) \cong \mathbf{Z}/1680$. Then, the fiber $Y'$ of this map $S^{15}\to
B\Spin(5)$ is a candidate for $Y$. I don't know how to construct a map $Y'\to \Spin(9)$.

Comment: You are quite right that $\mathrm{G}_2/\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is not a topological group.  Since, as you point out, there is a fibration $S^5\to \mathrm{G}_2/\mathrm{SU}(2)\to S^6$, all the homotopy groups $\pi_i(\mathrm{G}_2/\mathrm{SU}(2))$ for $i =0,1,2,3$  are trivial, so it can't be a compact Lie group.  Also, because $\pi_3\bigl(\mathrm{Spin}(9)/\mathrm{G}_2\bigr)$ is finite (probably trivial, but I haven't checked to be sure), it can't be a compact Lie group.  For similar reasons, your $Y$, if it exists, cannot be a topological group either.

Comment: Yep, thanks! (I also just added a construction of a candidate for Y.)